# Beginning of waveform chart empty

Tags: graph, charts, timestamp, labview

I have a LabVIEW VI that registers the temperature as a function of time. As you can see in the picture below the first part is empty and the X Autoscale keeps it like this. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you should check if the temperature is ready, then set a capture rate this temperature, using a "TIME DELAY".

Comment: I tried adding a Time Delay but that just delays everything instead of just loading temperature into the XY graph.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it happens.
You should try to disable autoscale and manually scale X axis.

Here is an example:

[image: Front panel]
[image: VI snippet]

Comment: I actually want to keep the autoscale because experiments can be from 20 minutes to 20 hours and dont want to keep changing it.

Comment: Even better! If you know in advance the duration of the test you can pre-scale X-axis and do it only once ! :)

Comment: Well I don't always know duration of the test and I use timestamp as x-axis scale so that is a nightmare to manually do everytime. That is the reason I want to keep autoscale on.

Answer (score 0):

click in the orange line, and put an indicator, verify if the first lines, there are something.

Maybe appear (nan) not a number

[image]

Comment: That is not the case, i also write data to a .csv file (removed from picture of block diagram for clarity) and no NaN are recorded in that file